# Redux: Cannot read property 'updateValue' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm trying to dispatch `inputValue` from my searchingBar to my `initialState` in reducer. When I try to push it to my state, i get that `updateValue` is undefined.

My reducer:

```
const initialState = {
    inputValue: ''
}

const inputSlice = createSlice({
    initialState,
    name: 'searchingBar',
    reducers: {
        updateValue: (state, action) => {
            state.inputValue = action.payload;
        }
    }
})

export default inputSlice.reducer;
```

and a searchingBar where I try to get `inputValue` from:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './SearchingBar.css'
import store from '../../store/store';
import inputSlice from '../../duck/reducer';

  const SearchingBar = ({shareToggleClass}) => {
    
    const [toggleClass, setToggleClass] = useState(false);
    const [query, setQuery] = useState('');

    const search = event => {
        if(event.key === "Enter") {
            setToggleClass(true);
            shareToggleClass({toggleClass})
            store.dispatch(inputSlice.actions.updateValue(query))
        }
    }
    return (
        <input type = "text"
          placeholder = "Search.."
          className = {toggleClass ? "Active" : "unActive"}
          onChange = {e => setQuery(e.target.value)}
          value = {query}
          onKeyPress = {search}
        />
    )
}

export default SearchingBar;
```

What causes the problem?
Here's my Github repo as well if its needed:
https://github.com/larryfisherman/weatherApp/tree/main/src

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you export `reducer` from slice and then try to get actions from this. Try this:

```js
// in slice file
export const { updateValue } = inputSlice.actions
export default inputSlice.reducer;

// somewhere you want to use it
import { updateValue } from './path/to/slice'
...
dispatch( updateValue( "payload" ) )
```

Comment: `export { updateValue } = inputSlice.actions` is the right syntax?

Comment: Yep.. you can see this on official redux page - https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createSlice

Comment: Yeah, nevermind I realised after link u sent. However, when I try to dispatch like u said I get that `distapch is not defined` and when I try to assign it as `store.dispatch` I get `Cannot read property 'type' of undefined`

Comment: Try to use dispatch hook from ```import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux'```

Comment: Nothing changed.

Comment: Check this example.. maybe it help you - https://codesandbox.io/s/loving-lamport-e6c7q?file=/src/App.js

Comment: I'm really confisued. When I try to dispatch I still get that `Cannot read property 'type' of undefined` and I don't see any differences between your code and mine. Do I need to use `useSelector` in my case?

Comment: Don't think so.. I used useSelector only for getting value but ```Cannot read property 'type'``` rather suggest that there is something wrong with your action. Can you provide codesandbox with bigger part of your code ?

Comment: Higher I gave my Github repo, but If you want me to I'll do it.

Comment: It will be much simpler if you include only components related to this issue.

Comment: Here it is: https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-chebyshev-do6p9?file=/src/components/WeatherBox/WeatherBox.jsx

Comment: @AlbertKarkut I got it.. the problem is with the way you import your functions. Add the curly braces. ```import { updateValue } from "../../duck/reducer";```

Comment: Thank you for your time and patience. I have just one more question. If i need more than one createSlice, do I want all of them to be seperate or all in one file?

Comment: You can use both solutions. Personally, I prefer to divide them into files with appropriate names.